# How do you create a FactoryGirl factory when your factory is reliant on another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm just learning how to use FactoryGirl. In my hotel_spec.rb, I've replaced

```
before { @hotel = Hotel.new(name: "The Holiday Inn", rating: 3.0) }
```

with

```
let(:hotel) { FactoryGirl.create(:hotel) }
```

and my spec/factories/hotels.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :hotel do |f|
        f.name "The Delano"
        f.rating 3.5
    end
end
```

So I'm going through and replacing my spec's where I've manually created objects like my @hotel object at the start of this post with factories.

Now I need to replace the following...

room_spec.rb

```
before(:each) do
    @hotel = Hotel.create(name: "The Inn", rating: 5.0)
    @room = Room.new(hotel_id: @hotel.id, number: 101, smoking: false, rate: 99.99)
end
```

How should this be done? I'm completely unaware of the syntax, I'm just looking for the syntax here. Also, should it be create a hotel factory and then pass it to room factory, or should room factory just create a hotel factory inside it and return the room. If it's the former or latter... what syntax do I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Hotel factory

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :hotel do
      name "The Delano"
      rating 3.5
    end
end

# Room Factory

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :room do
    number rand 0..100
    smoking false
    # ...
    association :hotel
  end
end
```

This way, when making a Room FactoryGirl will create a hotel using HotelFactory and associate room with it.

Also, If your association field name doesn't match class name you can pass factory name:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    association :author, factory: :user
  end
end
```

This way, author field will be filled by an object created from `UserFactory`

Comment: Is there a reason for downvote? This is a valid way of doing it and is how I do it. Furthermore, it's documented here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

Comment: Awesome thanks! So I don't need to set hotel_id then, just do the number/smoking/rate fields, and the association? Awesomely simple, thanks!

Comment: Exactly. No problem, I still don't understand why somebody downvoted it :)

Comment: Be sure to specify `strategy: :build` for the association, as it will default to `create`, and be triggered even if you `build` the parent. Unsure if this has been patched recently.

Answer (score 2):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :room do
    hotel
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl will automatically create a hotel for you when you create a room. If you need to specify a room, you can do so by doing `FactoryGirl.create(:room, hotel: hotel)`. Full documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations).